# Entity Framework: Any(..)-filtering with == matches NULL after upgrading from EF5 to EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

As part of upgrading my ASP.NET MVC project to target .NET Framework v4.8 and ASP.NET MVC v5.2.7, Entity Framework was also upgraded from v5.0.0 to v6.4.4; and after that I noticed a weird change using the `Any()` construct.

BTW I also followed the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/upgrading-to-ef6

I have this piece of code in my project (same code before and after the upgrade)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Course course)
{
    ...
    if (context.Courses.Any(c => c.ExternalCourseNumber == course.ExternalCourseNumber))
    {
        throw new Exception(Resources.Global.ExternalCourseIdAlreadyExists);
    }
    ...
}
```

It is a validation, that is part of creating a new `Course`. The `Course` object is the model passed to the Create method, and the field `ExternalCourseNumber` is left empty on the webform, and so `course.ExternalCourseNumber` has the value null, when I debug in Visual Studio.

The point is, that if an `ExternalCourseNumber` has been provided, it must not exist for any existing course, but when it has not been provided, I don't want to throw a validation error.

Prior to the upgrade, this validation would *not* throw a validation error, when `ExternalCourseNumber` is left empty/null. After the upgrade, my code throws a validation error.

I.e. it seems to me that:

```
Courses.Any(c => c.ExternalCourseNumber == course.ExternalCourseNumber)
```

have changed behaviour when comparing to null after the upgrade....and that is what puzzles me?!?

I know how to fix the issue by also testing for the null-value, but the change in behaviour worries me, as it may also affect other functionality, so I would like to understand what happened?

Did the == operator start to also match NULL-values or am I missing something?

=== UPDATE: SQL generated from EF6 =====

I managed to use the EF6 logging framework in order to see the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Courses] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ExternalCourseNumber] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[ExternalCourseNumber] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
    )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

...so that explains why the query will include courses where ExternalCourseNumber is null. But why/when did that change? Why doesn't EF5 behave in the same way? That seems like a "breaking change"?

PS I can't figure out how to see the SQL generated in EF5...any suggestions?

Comment: What does the generated sql look like?

Comment: @DavidL, Ah, right, good question - how can I "intercept" the SQL?

Comment: In `OnConfiguring`, you can add `options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);` (I guess that is working with EF 6 too)

Comment: I couldn't get the OnConfiguring-thing to work, but I managed to see the SQL via EF6's logging framework (https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/08/ef6-sql-logging-part-1-simple-logging/). The SQL has been listed in the main question.
...however, I can't figure out how to see the SQL generated in EF5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with a breaking change in *database null semantics*.

In EF6, a query like `context.Courses.Any(c => c.ExternalCourseNumber == course.ExternalCourseNumber)` will translate into something like:

```sql
WHERE ([Extent1].[ExternalCourseNumber] = @p__linq__0) 
    OR (([Extent1].[ExternalCourseNumber] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

(where `@p__linq__0` is a (n)varchar variable equal to `null`).

In EF5 this will be something like:

```sql
WHERE [Extent1].[ExternalCourseNumber] = @p__linq__0
```

The second query compares `null` to `null`, which in SQL is undefined, and the query returns nothing.

In EF6 this problem was fixed by making the comparison semantics equal to the semantics in C#, where `null == null` returns `true`. That required an additional `OR` predicate. The first query (EF6) returns courses where `ExternalCourseNumber` is `null`.

It's surprising that this breaking change isn't clearly documented. In EF5, `ObjectContext` already had a setting `ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior` by which the behavior could be changed. The default was `false`; setting it to `true` turned the SQL translation into that of the first query.

In EF6 this setting was moved to the preferred `DbContext` as `DbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics`, so, in fact, the opposite of `UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior`. The breaking change was that the default was also `false`, probably because the C# semantics were deemed to be the preferred behavior, as it would be what most EF developers would expect.

In your case I wouldn't change `UseDatabaseNullSemantics`, but simply add an extra check if `course.ExternalCourseNumber` is not equal to `null`, because it makes the code more self-explanatory.

Comment: Ah, that explains it...and great explanation of the settings on the contexts (weird that they chose to make it "opposite" incl. the default values). Thanks!!!